# How do I achieve this effect?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

There are 50+ categories on my site,i want each category to achieve this effect:One row ,4 products.

I do not clone views one by one.
Anyone can help me? THX

Note:I use drupal 7.

Comment: You can use category (taxonomy) as `contextual filter` in views and can use css to display four item in a row.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) I'm afraid this type of question isn't a good fit for our Q+A format, and so needs to be closed. Specifically, it's about _Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided_, which would be better suited to a support forum, or somewhere you can request tutorials to be written. Unfortunately we don't do either of those things here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Views Fluid Grid](https://drupal.org/project/views_fluid_grid) module

This module provides the Fluid Grid style plugin for Views. This plugin displays the view as a fluid grid using an HTML list element.

> The plugin settings form provides options to define the width and
>   height of the elements in the grid. But it also provides advanced
>   layout options implemented in separate CSS classes that allow you to
>   define item margins, alignment and a couple of CSS3 properties
>   (box-shadow and border-radius).